# Magento 2 Gift Card Message Text area want maximum 220 characters only?

Tags: magento2, cart, giftmessage

I enable gift option from magento 2 admin end. Now i want to make gift card message text area need to allow maximum 220 characters only.

[image]

How do we achieve this?

Thanks